# как сортировать два "половинных" массива в сортировке слиянием?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

[в этом видeо](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQMSowIS2FY&list=WL&index=1&ab_channel=%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4) увидел на 0:45 - 0:56 то, что нужно отсортировать половинки массива, но автор не указал как. По идее, время выполнения сортировки слиянием равно `n*log(n)`, но что, если два этих половинных массивов мы будем сортировать разными методами? Тогда, вроде, не будет достигнуто заявленное время (как мне кажется).
Вопрос: каким методом нужно сортировать два "половинных" массива?

Comment: Сортировкой слияния. В вашем видео об этом говорится на 5-ой минуте

Comment: а может просто разделить сразу массив из n элементов на n/2 массивов, где в каждом массиве, соответственно, 2 элемента (случай с четным кол-вом)? Да, конечно, пронумеровав эти массивы (засунув их в другой массив, а эти сделать подмассивами)

Comment: В нерекурсивной реализации примерно так и делается, однако сами попробуйте написать рекурсивную и нерекурсивную версии. Первую я могу написать за минуту, а вторую ни разу в жизни не писал вообще, а если бы пришлось, то убил бы кучу нервов

Comment: разве нерекурсивный метод не быстрее, чем рекурсивный?

Comment: Какая связь между рекурсией и скоростью?

Comment: Быстрее, разумеется, но нервы программиста в данном случае стоят дороже, чем сортировка, реализованная оптимальными способами в библиотеках уже тысячу раз

Comment: в некоторых случаях прямая. Допустим, написание рекурсивного алгоритма поиска факториала медленнее, чем нерекурсивный. Я распространил этот вывод и на данный случай, но, кажется, ошибся

Comment: я учусь писать алгоритмы сортировки, мне не нужна функция из библиотеки для оптимизации приложения или для подобной вещи

Comment: Для факториала разница в скорости из за разных алгоритмов, но не из за рекурсии как таковой. Я могу написать рекурсивное вычисление факториала, которое по скорости не уступит нерекурсивному. Более того, некоторые ркурсии автоматически разворачиваются компилятором в нерекурсивный код. Попрактикуйтесь в оценке сложности алгоритмов, это вам даст понимание как и что.

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, нахождение факториала за кол-во операций меньшее, чем у цикла. Ели не трудно, то на JS, за другие языки программирования никогда не брался

Comment: я не знаю, какую реализацию вы имели ввиду, но простейшая вида `fact(int number) { if number == 1 return 1; return number * fact(number -1); }` имеет точно такую асимптотику, как и цикл. По сути, тут цикл заменен рекурсией. см [Хвостовая рекурсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: @tym32167 Асимптотика асимптотикой, а время выполнения может отличаться. Где какой оптимизатор - вот для VC++: https://rextester.com/LZL84268, тут для GCC - https://ideone.com/aTuZSc, но тут явно компилятор рекурсию убрал совсем.

Comment: @Harry я только хотел дать понять автору, что рекурсия не всегда медленней итерации, есть много всяких факторов, что влияют на скорость работы алгоритма, даже используемый язык имеет значение.

Answer (score 1):

Идея именно в том, что каждая половинка сортируется **тем же методом** - сортировкой слияния. Именно отсюда и вытекает сложность алгоритма O(N*log(N)).

Что до рекурсия-итерация: да, *в общем случае* рекурсия медленнее (не в смысле сложности алгоритма!) из-за вызова функции, но эта разница не так уж велика, а оптимизатором часто просто убирается вовсе.